# Baggage movement help at Seattle airport

Tags: air-travel, international-travel

My daughter with her post surgery shoulder, will be arriving at Seattle airport, with her 5 yrs' son and four check-in luggage, in mid-November 2019. Though she is now fit for air travel, she will face inconvenience to move her luggage bags from belt to outside through customs and immigration.

Is there any service/help available at Seattle airport to move the luggage bags outside?

Comment: Has she considered to ask for help both on the departure and the arrival airport? You can ask also when you have a temporary problem and also when you can walk well. The airports will supply what help is needed, based on what they are told.

Comment: She contacted Singapore Airlines, the flight operators; they asked to seek help airport help at Seattle. But we do not know whom to contact. Thanks.

Comment: The address to contact is hidden somewhere on this page, (or you may use the app if you have a suitable telephone) but I can not find the right service for you. https://www.portseattle.org/sea-tac/accessibility-at-sea-tac-airport

Comment: I'm surprised Singapore Airlines did not handle her request and arrange for the service directly. There's actually a special form just for this for flights to/from the US here: https://www.singaporeair.com/showSplAssistance.form -- the "Meet and Assist" option would seem to be exactly what she needs.

Comment: Most US airports have "baggage porter" in the baggage claim area. They were a uniform, have large carts and you can just waive them over or they announce their services. They work for tip, $20 should be plenty. They have security and immigration access so they can work in the international area and haul your bags through customs. However, I they have become a bit rarer recently and I could not find any reliable source whether there are any in Seatac at the moment

Comment: @Hilmar wave them over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sea-Tac airport states that arranging this kind of assistance [is the responsibility of the airline](https://www.portseattle.org/services-amenities/accessible-transportation-and-wheelchair-services).

> If you need assistance getting from the airline ticket counter through security and to your gate, please arrange this directly with your airline. This service is provided at no charge, but gratuities are greatly appreciated.
>
> From Your Ticket Counter to Your Departure Gate
>
> Please contact your airline directly to make a reservation prior to your arrival at the airport.
>
> From Your Arrival Gate to Baggage Claim
>
> Please contact your airline directly to make a reservation prior to your arrival at the airport.

You stated that you only need assistance after baggage claim, so perhaps this is why Singapore Airlines suggested that you contact the airport. Hence, it might be easier to request assistance for the whole journey. It's not unreasonable for someone recovering from shoulder surgery to request being helped all the way from the plane. The Sea-Tac site doesn't really explain how to get assistance after baggage claim, but I can't imagine that in this case your daughter will just be left to fend for herself. Almost certainly, help can be arranged from baggage claim to the taxi rank.

Your daughter should contact Singapore Airlines again using [this form](https://www.singaporeair.com/showSplAssistance.form) and request "Meet and Assist". Or, if the journey is within the next 72 hours, she should [phone their Seattle office](https://www.singaporeair.com/contactUs.form) on 1-800-742-3333.

Answer (score 0):

There will be help available [according to iFly.com](https://www.ifly.com/seattle-tacoma-international/medical-handicapped-disabilities).

It says to arrange this with the airline, but as you have already contacted the airline, you can [contact the airport by telephone](https://www.portseattle.org/contacts/sea-tac-airport-customer-service).

I also can’t imagine another passenger not helping you as well. There are a lot of luggage trollies, so I’m sure someone can get one for you and help put your bags on it but you should get help arranged in advance.

Comment: What is ifly? It doesn't seem to be an official site. And the Sea Tac website seems to say that the airline should be contacted to arrange assistance. I also think relying on other passengers to help is a slightly bizarre idea.

Comment: @MJeffryes I did say to contact the airline, but the airline already said to contact the airport as seen in the comments

Comment: @Daniil Please don't use generic link text like  "read more" or "click here"; it's [unfriendly for accessibility](https://webaccess.berkeley.edu/ask-pecan/click-here) and search indexing, and [needlessly non-contextual](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/learn-more-links/).